# How to find matches between strings into two array - java

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays containing some strings like the following:

Array #1

```
abcd                    
efgh            
servicegroup_1
ijkl
```

Array #2

```
servicegroup_3
servicegroup_1
```

I'd like to print a string like `"VERIFY: OK"` (on console) if the Array #1 contains at least one of the strings of Array #2. Otherwise, a string `"VERIFY: KO"` have to be printed.

I implemented some code like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scopeFile.length; i++) {
                for (String element : scopeJWT) {
                    if (scopeFile[i].contains(element)) {
                        ctx.setSendZuulResponse(true);
                        System.out.println(now + " --- " + "[Check Signature: OK]" + " [Verify Scope: OK]" + " [Verify expTime: OK]");
                    } else {
                        ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
                        ctx.setResponseStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                        System.err.println(now + " --- " + "[VERIFY SCOPE: KO]");
                    }
                }
}
```

but, it returns both `VERIFY SCOPE: OK` and `VERIFY SCOPE: KO`, even if in considering the arrays I reported, I would have printed just `VERIFY SCOPE: OK`(because Array #1 contains `servicegroup_1`)

Any ideas to fix my code? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to break the loop after the string is found in Array1.
Try adding a `break;` after this line:

```
System.out.println(now + " --- " + "[Check Signature: OK]" + " [Verify Scope: OK]" + " [Verify expTime: OK]");
```

And check **non-ok** case outside the loop.

like this:

```
boolean isOk = false;
for (int i = 0; i < scopeFile.length; i++) {
    for (String element : scopeJWT) {
        if (scopeFile[i].contains(element)) {
            ctx.setSendZuulResponse(true);
            System.out.println(now + " --- " + "[Check Signature: OK]" + " [Verify Scope: OK]" + " [Verify expTime: OK]");
            isOk = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!isOk) {
    ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
    ctx.setResponseStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    System.err.println(now + " --- " + "[VERIFY SCOPE: KO]");
}
```

Comment: Just tried. It prints both the strings

Comment: I edited the answer just now. Try the latest version.